# Given $x=a+bi$ is a solution of the polynomial equation $c_4z^4+ic_3z^3+c_2z^2+ic_1z+c_0=0$ show that $x=-a+bi$ is also a solution

Tags: polynomials

> Suppose $x=a+bi$ is a solution of the polynomial equation
>   $$c_4z^4+ic_3z^3+c_2z^2+ic_1z+c_0=0$$ where $c_0,c_1,c_2,c_3,c_4,a,$
>   and $b$ are real constants and $i^2=-1$.
>
> Show that $-a+bi$ is also a solution

Since $x=a+bi$ is a solution of the above equation I have that

$a^4 c_4+\color{red}{4 i a^3 b c_4}+\color{red}{i a^3 c_3}-6 a^2 b^2 c_4-3 a^2 b c_3+a^2 c_2\color{red}{-4 i a b^3 c_4}-3 i a b^2 c_3+\color{red}{2 i a b c_2}+\color{red}{i a c_1}+b^4 c_4+b^3 c_3-b^2 c_2-b c_1+c_0 = 0 $

Now I want to show that $x=-a+bi$ is also a solution which means that I have to prove that

$a^4 c_4-4 i a^3 b c_4-i a^3 c_3-6 a^2 b^2 c_4-3 a^2 b c_3+a^2 c_2+4 i a b^3 c_4+3 i a b^2 c_3-2 i a b c_2-i a c_1+b^4 c_4+b^3 c_3-b^2 c_2-b c_1+c_0 = 0 $

The terms that have been marked with red  are the terms which are different from the last equation $(3)$.

Now, I simple don't know what to do.

Also I know I am definetly missing the simple approach because I don't think the author would have liked to "play" so much with the algebra as I did.

Comment: You can't say that the complex conjugate of a root is a root when you have imaginary coefficients, because the coefficients aren't fixed by conjugation.  For example $iz+1$ has root $i$, but $-i$ is not a root.

Comment: I didn't know that.

Comment: I've edited .Sorry for the mistake....@rVitale

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let your original polynomial be $p(z).$ Note that if one defines $q(u)=p(iu)$ then $q$ has real coefficients. Since $z=a+bi$ is a zero of $p,$ if we put $u=-i(a+bi)=b-ai$ then $iu=a+bi.$ Here $u$ is a zero of $q$ so since $q$ has real coefficients the conjugate $b+ai$ is also a zero of $q.$ Then multiply $b+ai$ by $i$ to get to $-a+bi$ being a zero of $p.$

Comment: Do you want to put $u=-i(a+bi)$ so that $iu=a+bi$?

Comment: So this is not the correct answer ?

Comment: @rVitale I think you're right. I just rushed too much since it seemed the substitution worked so well. I'll fix (and credit your comment).

Comment: @rVitale Thanks for the edit, and catching yet another two errors in the write-up. (at the end I should *multiply* by $i$ (divide by $-i$) to go back.

Comment: @coffeemath No problem, you gave a really nice solution.

Comment: @Mr.Y The answer is correct as far as I can tell.

Comment: My comment was not meant to be offensive,I was confused given that your comment suggested to me that there was something wrong.However now it's all clear about the solution of the problem.Thank you coffeemath.The trick was all about to get a polynomial with real coefficients !(Btw what would have been an other way of solving the problem if you would think about it ?)

Comment: @Mr.Y To me that was the simplest way to solve it. Maybe direct substitution would have worked, but then multiplying out powers of a+bi would get messy.